# Arguments against Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, fedora, distribution-choice, distributions

As someone who's been using Ubuntu for a couple of years now both in production and at home, when seeking answers to certain administrative questions for my systems, I often hear the "that's what you get for being on [Ubuntu | Debian]" comment, seemingly indicating that there's something fundamentally ineffective about this specific distro that I'm using. Often you'll hear CentOS/RHEL/Fedora recommended instead.

E.g. argument would be: "*Ubuntu starts services by default on `apt-get install` instead of allowing to you change their `configs` before boot*", which sometimes can be convenient when working with configuration management tools.

Personally I don't care too much about any specific distro, but I do deeply care about productivity, simplicity, stability and availability of latest versions of critical packages.

Now, would anyone be so kind as to explain why Ubuntu tends to receive much criticism from the Linux community, and what my options are? What would be some of the gains if I were to switch to a different distro?

Comment: No need to add specifics here. The question was good when kept generic.

Comment: @Tshepang details and examples could never hurt: http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Comment: I would start to research the facts behind "the(ir) arguments" first. Posting some "arguments" would help to clarify where "they" might have a point where one can start to change things to a better. As Linux Distributions are highly configurable, the elements are highly interchangeable etc. "thats what you get for…" sound snobbish to me. Upgrading a media-center oriented Linux to a heavily used (whatever) server surely could be an experience - but there are other Distros better suited for this task(s). Posting this question in http://askubuntu.com/ might not be very friendly.

Comment: I personally have three bones to pick with Ubuntu: 1) The Unity interface 2) The fact that [dash searches end up as Amazon searches!!](http://arstechnica.com/business/2012/09/ubuntu-bakes-amazon-search-results-into-os-to-raise-cash/) 3) The Unity interface. The Unity interface is a serious obstacle to productivity when compared with the traditional taskbar-window-list approach. The Amazon searches thing a) is too much commercialism for my taste b) may slow down searches when trying to access amazon

Comment: @JosephR. You don't have any of those things on a server though.

Comment: @jordanm, OP didn't specify "server". Anyway, the question seems quite open-ended and capable of generating opinion.

Comment: The question is tendentious and disclosing the "certain administrative questions" you speak of would have helped considerably. What's "ineffective" really? Admittedly I don't have the expertise to discuss the server side of things, but in relation to the desktop I can only say that my experience of Xubuntu has been a top notch one. People who didn't like Unity could turn Ubuntu into that with one command. Since you used it yourself for years I think you know its track record. I think elitism and an unfriendly approach to GPL are the culprits behind this seemingly unsubstantiated criticism.

Comment: After switching to another distro, you'll likely find a new crowd saying you should switch to Ubuntu/Debian for other various reasons.

Comment: @drs Completely agreed. This seems to generate as much heated debate as your choice of text editor...